# javascript - merge objects return arrays with the keys and sum of values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object like this, but I need to manipulate to return 2 arrays with the keys and the sum of the data. Considering that this data can grow indefinitely.

```
const data = [
  {
    year: 2017,
    month: 1,
    sources: {
      source1: 50,
      source2: 30,
      source3: 10
    }
  },
  {
    year: 2017,
    month: 2,
    sources: {
      source1: 50,
      source2: 10
    }
  },
  {
    year: 2017,
    month: 3,
    sources: {
      source1: 10,
      source2: 10,
      source3: 1
    }
  }
]
```

I need the result to be and Array of strings and in order and with the sum of the sources data

```
const sources = ["source1", "source2", "source3"]
const data = [160, 50, 1]
```

Comment: [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is your friend =)

Comment: I'm struggling to figure out how data[0] (assuming this is the sum of all `source1` properties?) ends up being 60? Likewise with source2 and source3

Comment: What is the logic to get `[60, 40, 1]`

Comment: *"...I've been struggling a lot to get that solve."* Post the code you've been struggling with.

Comment: @Xufox I think OP meant "source1", "source2", and "source3"

Comment: They are the keys and they can be different, like airbnb:10, bookingcom:20, x:30.

Comment: Can you post **exactly** what you expect to get back with the data that you've given in your snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the objects into a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) by iterating the sources of each object using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). You spread the Map's [keys iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/keys) to get the sources array, and spread the [values iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) to get the values array:

```js
const data = [{"year":2017,"month":1,"sources":{"source1":50,"source2":30,"source3":10}},{"year":2017,"month":2,"sources":{"source1":50,"source2":10}},{"year":2017,"month":3,"sources":{"source1":10,"source2":10,"source3":1}}]

const sourcesMap = data.reduce((m, { sources }) => { 
  Object.entries(sources).forEach(([key, value]) => m.set(key, (m.get(key) || 0) + value))

  return m;
}, new Map())

const sources = [...sourcesMap.keys()]
const values = [...sourcesMap.values()]

console.log(sources)
console.log(values)
```